# No me sirve el length para contar el total de elementos

Tags: javascript

No logro contar la cantidad de items que cumplen con la condición de tener el color *red* ya que como lo tengo en este ejemplo solo me muestra la cantidad de caracteres de cada item encontrado con esa condición, mas no el total de items encontrados con esa condición. Qué puedo hacer?

```js
var a = [

{
"text": "uno",
"color": "red"
},
{
"text": "dos",
"color": "red"
},
{
"text": "tres",
"color": "yellow"
}
];


for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

var b = a[i].color;

if (b == "red") {

alert(b.length); // ME MUESTRA LA CANTIDAD DE CARACTERES DE CADA ITEM ENCONTRADO

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
const a = [

{
"text": "uno",
"color": "red"
},
{
"text": "dos",
"color": "red"
},
{
"text": "tres",
"color": "yellow"
}
];

const totalRed = a.filter(e => e.color === "red").length;

alert(totalRed);
```

Basicamente `filter` lo que hace es devolvernos los elementos de un array que cumplan con una condicion, en este caso la condicion viene dada por:

```
e.color === "red"
```

Es decir, que el elemento tenga como valor `"red"` en su propiedad `color`, en caso de que la condicion sea cierta nos encola en un nuevo array ese elemento, en caso contrario lo descarta.

Esto ultimo nos permite tener un array que contiene solo aquellos elementos que cumplan con esta condicion, y pues el resultado al ser un array podemos sacarle el `length` para saber la cantidad de elementos que poseen el color `red`:

```
a.filter(e => e.color === "red").length
```